# Auto accept "Configuring iptables-persistent"

Tags: linux, bash, sh, iptables

i'm created bash script where i need to configure network, but in one of stage he ask me to save new rule, how to prevent it and set "Yes" automatically.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1443

sudo apt-get -y install iptables-persistent

sudo service netfilter-persistent save
```

[message where he ask to save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq6E9.jpg)

Comment: `echo "Yes" | <your command>`?

Comment: @Cyrus he ask me to save, not "Yes" word

Comment: `echo | <your command>`?

Comment: @Cyrus: No, it won't work. See my answer. That is what he needs

Comment: @Sam.L.: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Cyrus yes, and it didn't work, cause you suggest use pipe but in my case i need to confirm action in dialog screen

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: `tmux -L dialog-session new-session -d apt -y install iptables-persistent && 
tmux -L dialog-session send-keys Enter && 
tmux -L dialog-session send-keys Enter` worked for me

Comment: Before installing iptables-persistent i type this:
echo iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v4 boolean true | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v6 boolean true | sudo debconf-set-selections

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**For non-terminal programs**

Actually, you can always automatize input of eny word with several methods:

```
 yes word | command
```

(in this `word` will be entered as an input of `command`)
or using `expect`, if you need more sophisticated dialog.

**For terminal programs** (your case)

For interactive sessions you can try it this way:

1. start it in a tmux session
2. send "Enter" using `tmux send-keys`

That is exactly what you want.

```
tmux send-keys Enter
```

Everything combined:

```
sudo tmux -L dialog-session new-session -d service netfilter-persistent save
sudo tmux -L dialog-session send-keys Enter
```

(actually you don't need `sudo` here, but I use `sudo` because of your `sudo`)

Comment: maybe somehow, set `interactive sessions` to noninteractive? Or it will not help?

Comment: @Sam.L.Just use `tmux`, it is a trivial question, really

Comment: @Sam.L. I've updated the answer with a full example. Just try it and see it works

Comment: yeah, with example works fine